# Handling multiple Foreign keys from mutiple models in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have my parishioner model like below (Only pasting relevant CODE)

```
class Parishioner(models.Model):
    family = models.ForeignKey(Family, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='members')
    role = models.ForeignKey(FamilyRole, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='role')
```

Parishioner can have `one Family` and `One role` in that family

So I'm trying to achieve this in my Family Serializer.

```
class FamilySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    members = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True,
        queryset=Parishioner.objects.all(),
        allow_null=True,
        required=False
    )

    role = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True,
        queryset=FamilyRole.objects.all(),
        allow_null=True,
        required=False
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Family
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'address', 'monthly_contribution', 'members', 'role', 'enabled')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
        depth = 1
```

Basically What I'm trying to do is When I add family I can add members(Parishioners) to that family and assign a role each member.

What am I doing wrong here ?
because when I load my `api/family/`

I'm getting below error

```
'Family' object has no attribute 'role'
```

But you can clearly see I added `related_name='role'` in my Parishioner model.

So how can I achieve what I want ?

I want to add members(Parishioners) to Family and assign Role to each member in that Family.

Examples for `FamilyRole`: Father, Mother, son, daughter

My front end will be similar to this in my Create Family page (and I expect to send only one request to server to achieve this by using `api/family/` endpoint)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing `depth` or setting it to 2? You clearly have a field `role` in your serializer, my guess is Django is not recognizing it because of the `depth` option.

Then you would ask me why it is recognizing the field `members`? It's not, that didn't raise an error because you have a related_name `family` in your `Parishoner` Model.

Comment: **you have a related_name `members` in your `Parishoner` Model**, sorry for the misspelling

Comment: yes I tried removing/changing depth, and YES members did NOT raise error. All I want to do is add members(Parishioners) to Family and assign Role to each member in that Family.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few question in your post.

```
class Parishioner(models.Model):
    family = models.ForeignKey(Family, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='members')
    role = models.ForeignKey(FamilyRole, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='role')
```

So `Partishioner` has a `role` column.

```
class FamilySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Family
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'address', 'monthly_contribution', 'members', 'role', 'enabled')
```

In serializer you try to access `role` of `Family`.

```
'Family' object has no attribute 'role'
```

I guess your `Family` model doesn't have `role` column but `Parishioner` has.

Comment: yes thats the issue. So how can I achieve what I want ?
Basically when I create family I want to assign members and roles to each member of the family